# Styled pandas dataframe in Dash-Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash

I have pandas data frame and am using the "df_styled = df.style.apply(...)" method to style the values in data frame conveniently (in a Jupyter Notebook).
However, I am unable to display this styled output when using Dash-Plotly dashboard.

Can someone suggest anything?

I have tried df_styled.render() method but this shows a string representation of my styled dataframe on Dash-dashboard and not the HTML output (as I get in Jupyter notebook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of directly using the styled components of Pandas, I would recommend the below

1. Transform your dataframe to a plotly-dash datatable
2. Format the dash datatable based on the plotly-dash documentation.

an example code would be as below

```
mytable = dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table1',
    columns=[{"name": i, "id": i,'type':'numeric', 'format': {'specifier': ',.0f'}}  if i not in ['phone_number'] else {"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    style_as_list_view=True,
    style_cell={'padding': '2px'},
    page_action='none',
    style_table={'height': '600px', 'overflowY': 'auto'},
    style_cell_conditional=[
    {
        'if': {'column_id': 'phone_number'},
        'textAlign': 'center'
    },
],
    style_data_conditional=[
    {
        'if': {'row_index': 0},
        'backgroundColor': '#FFF2CC',
    },
],
    style_header={
        'backgroundColor': 'white',
        'fontWeight': 'bold',
        'textAlign': 'center'
    },
)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. Appreciate it. I am in a twist as previously I have a working solution for Jupyter and streamlit using styled dataframes). For Dash-Plotly I was hoping to reduce the overhead of conversion. If what I am trying to achieve does not work out then probably your solution is the one which I might consider. I will wait for some time if any solution appears which works on my existing code.

Comment: @codebraker I think you should award the answer above

Comment: @ConnorFerster the comment can't be awarded as it is not entered as an answer.

Comment: One drawback to this is that the Dash DataTable does not have a good display for timedelta objects. Thus if your data has any columns of that type (timedelta64) it will not be a pleasant view of those cells. Thus if converting from widgets, you lose the tie default that jupyter gives you on display.

Comment: @TheRealBill Hanalia answered the question. I am not referring to the comment.

Comment: @codebraker I know this is really late and you've probably moved on. I use Pandas styled tables in my app. Have you tried passing your Pandas table to an "html.Iframe" object in your callbacks section? You can then serve this directly to a "html.div" in the layout. I had same issue and this was the solution.